# How to add time in countdown in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I found a piece of code that works, but I don't know how I can edit this code to replace time to the countdown after submit.

```
var countdown =  $("#countdown").countdown360({
    radius      : 60,
    seconds     : 60 * 5,
    fontColor   : '#FFFFFF',
    autostart   : false,
    onComplete  : function () { location.reload(); }
});
countdown.start();
```

Comment: When you say after submit what exactly do you mean? Are you submitting some type of form after the countdown is already initialized?

Comment: Hi @ChrisCruz , I need replace second after click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call:

```
countdown.addSeconds(secs) // Replace secs with extension time in seconds.
```

The API docs are [here](https://github.com/johnschult/jquery.countdown360).

Comment: Hi, I need replace second, but this code previous adds to seconds.

Comment: @mySun I believe this is what you are looking for. Essentially you may be able to remove 'seconds: 60 * 5' completely or just set it to 'seconds: 0' to avoid defaults. Then, you would later after the click call the countdown.addSeconds(x) method.

Comment: @ChrisCruz Thank you for help me :-)